# CSS remove width from div

Tags: html, css

I have code:

```
<div class="ipsType_richText">
    <div class="ipsContained">
        <div class="ipsType_richText">
            <div style="box-sizing: border-box; table-layout: fixed; width: 723px; color: rgb(101, 101, 101); font-size: 14px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
                my html code...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I remove `width: 723px` from div style? I can't add class to that div, because that div generated looks like by ckeditor. I've tried smth like `.ipsType_richText .div{ width: 100%; }` but It not works. Is it possible to do that without touching js?

Comment: try `.ipsType_richText div{ width: 100% !important; }`. BTW  `div` isn't a class

Comment: @Banzay ohh, thanks so much

Comment: I transfered comment to an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to define

```
.ipsType_richText div{ width: 100% !important; }.
```

BTW `div` isn't a class so you don't need to put a dot `.` with div in the selector.